# Mongoose - How can I make this data more usable?

Tags: json, mongoose

I have the following data strucutre outputting form my Schema in a node/express app. I'd like to have the feeds array simply an array of name:key pairs. I don't like the sort of weird numbered object structure going on between "feeds" and the actual feeds data. But i can't figure out how to manually define that in mongoose. any help would be awesome. thanks!

outputted JSON

```
{
"title": "Testing",
"created_at": "2011-10-05T16:23:26.217Z",
"feeds": [{
    "0": {
        "name": "twitter",
        "key": "person1"
    },
    "1": {
        "name": "twitter",
        "key": "person2"
    },
    "_id": "4e8c847e02edc10035000003"
}]
```

}

i want this:

```
{
  "title": "Testing",
  "created_at": "2011-10-05T16:23:26.217Z",
  "feeds": [
    {
      "name": "twitter",
      "key": "person1"
    },
    {
      "name": "twitter",
      "key": "person2"
    }
  ],
  "_id": "4e8c847e02edc10035000003"
}
```

this is my schema:

```
var Feed = new Schema({
  name        : { type: String }
, key         : { type: String }
});

var Page = new Schema({
    title         : { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } }
  , feeds         : [Feed]
  , created_at    : { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a colleague was able to answer this for me. My bad for not posting the relevant code, I didn't realize where the problem actually was. But for those who may encounter this problem:

If you push your embedded docs into the model when saving, you may need to do a forEach loop rather than pushing the embedded docs (in this case Feeds) together. Using forEach, the database saved the feeds directly to the feeds array rather than creating those weird groupings.

This pushed the feeds in properly:

```
  req.body.feed.forEach(function(feed){
     page.feeds.push(feed);
  });
```

Let me know if you have the same problem and need more explanation.